# How to take user input when executing one Perl script from another

Tags: perl, perl-module

#### test1.pl

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
print "enter the user data";
$var=<>;
print "the entered data:$var";
```

#### test2.pl

```
#! usr\bin\perl
$var=`test2.pl`;
print $var;
```

When executing `test2.pl` it doesn't work. How can it be solved?

Comment: You are calling `test2.pl` in `test2.pl`, why? What are you expecting from `test2.pl`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `require` to execute the another program. Try this

**test1.pl**

```
print "enter the user data ";
chomp($var=<>);
print "the entered data:$var\n";
```

**test2.pl**

```
require "test1.pl";
print "$var\n";
```

Then easily access the `$var` from the `test1.pl`.